# Split this method c#

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public void makecall(int TransmitPhoneLoc, int ReceivePhoneLoc)
{
    clsPhone Tphone = (clsPhone) phoneArray[TransmitPhoneLoc];
    clsPhone Rphone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[ReceivePhoneLoc];
    Tphone.ringPhone();
    Rphone.ringPhone();
    //Tphone.hello();
}
```

I'm trying to split it into two methods so that I can use `Tphone` and `Rphone` independently of each other. Here's my latest attempt... sucks I know but I'm trying!

```
public clsPhone incoming(int TransmitPhoneLoc)
{
    clsPhone Tphone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[TransmitPhoneLoc];
    return Tphone;
}

public clsPhone Outgoing(int ReceivePhoneLoc)
{
    clsPhone Rphone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[ReceivePhoneLoc];
    return Rphone;      
}

public void makecall()
{
    // Rphone and Tphone do something?      
}
```

Any help on how I can use these two objects independently will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
The problem is I'm unsure how to take the values from the two methods I have created instead of the original method and implement them in the same manner as the original method. So the third method is making calls to the first and second method. I have tried to do it like this as I will have other methods such as `endcall`.

Here is my fianl solution, thankyou all for trying, I know it's not easy understanding what a novice like me is trying to accomplish. Thankyou Dilvid for the inspiration to my final solution. I hope it's clear now what I wanted to do. I have a method in my ClsPhone to setup a connection, this activates in the ClsExchange. There will be other methods to end a call etc.

```
public clsPhone incoming(int TransmitPhoneLoc)
    {
        clsPhone Tphone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[TransmitPhoneLoc];
        return Tphone;
    }
    public clsPhone Outgoing(int ReceivePhoneLoc)
    {

        clsPhone Rphone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[ReceivePhoneLoc];
        return Rphone;

    }
    public void makecall(int tpc, int opc)
    {
        Outgoing(tpc).ringPhone();
        incoming(opc).ringPhone();




    }
```

Comment: I guess I dont understand the problem.

Comment: Edit it in a way to make us understand how these objects interact.  Does the maker need to call the reciever?  Or give us some business rules or idea on what this is all supposed to do.

Comment: As a side note, your code is rather difficult to read since you are capitalizing your types and variables in the reverse of the standard convention.  Classes, types and methods should be capitalized, local variables should be lowercase.

Comment: In addition to what Moozhe said, you're using hungarian notation, abbreviations not commonly known, using late binding collections... I could go on, but in general, ugh, I had a hard time even looking at this to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You final solution is not good practise. you should not have two functions for doing the same task. See the alternative answer in my post for how to use one function to get the phone you want to ring

Comment: @musefan what i really want to do is just get the two objects and use them like class level variables wothout having to go through the constructor process each time..if that makes any sense whatsoever. Is it possible to do it as two properties?

Comment: sure is, I dont know a lot about your class but I will add another bit of code to my answer to help with what I think you are asking. Hold tight

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to do, but what about this - is it along the right lines?

```
public void MakeCall(int phoneLoc)
{
   clsPhone phone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[phoneLoc];
   phone.ringPhone();
}
```

Usage: as the OP code suggests prior knowledge of index values for both received and transmitted phones in the array the method can be used like so...

```
MakeCall(tpc);
//and/or
MakeCall(opc);
```

**Alternatively** you can do this...

```
public clsPhone GetPhone(int phoneLoc)
{
   return (clsPhone)phoneArray[phoneLoc];
}
```

usage:

```
GetPhone(tpc).ringPhone();
//and/or
GetPhone(opc).ringPhone();
```

**Class Level Usage Option:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    clsPhone[] phoneArray;//set this however
    int tpc = 1;
    int opc = 2;

    clsPhone Tphone { get { return GetPhone(tpc); } }
    clsPhone Rphone { get { return GetPhone(opc); } }

    private clsPhone GetPhone(int phoneLoc)
    {
        return (clsPhone)phoneArray[phoneLoc];
    }

    public void MakeCall()
    {
        Tphone.ringPhone();
        Rphone.ringPhone();
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: But whose phone is `phone` ringing to?  I would think you'd pass it a receiving object.

Comment: @JonH: It will ring the phone based on the "phoneLoc" param. The op obviously already knows these based on the two methods they wrote priviously.

Comment: but your answer doesn't do proper communication between receiving and transmitting.

Comment: @JonH: in the OP code, apart from the param names there is no difference between receiving and tranmitting. Both use same class type (clsPhone) and both use same array (phoneArray)

Comment: but that's the problem, what is the purpose of such a class, that could ultimately be the concern of the OP and your answer leaves that up in the air.  Not upvoting or downvoting just saying.

Comment: I hear what your saying, I would ideally have MakeCall be a function of the clsPhone class. But this question is not about how to design classes properly (I don't think we have enough information to suggest that), the question asked how to separated the method to allow phones to be called individually, for which I have provided a solution (IMHO)

Comment: @musefan  Doh, im being dumb. Thanks for the extra work on the propertie but i understand now what I need to be doing. Instead of having two methods to get two different objects i call the same method twice with different parameters. As you can tell im someone with a non systematic brain trying desperately to make sense of OOP. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the first two methods to this (ignoring the non-standard naming conventions you've chosen):

```
public clsPhone incoming(int TransmitPhoneLoc) {
    return phoneArray[TransmitPhoneLoc] as clsPhone;
}

public clsPhone Outgoing(int ReceivePhoneLoc) {
    return phoneArray[ReceivePhoneLoc] as clsPhone;
}
```

And your last method as:

```
public void makecall() {
    // You'll need to have the values for rPhoneLoc / tPhoneLoc set somewhere
    //   or as parameters to this method
    var rPhone = Outgoing(rPhoneLoc);
    var tPhone = Incoming(tPhoneLoc);

    rPhone.ringPhone(tPhone);
}
```

I realize that your `ringPhone` method may not currently accept an argument for the destination to call. This refactor might make sense given how you're trying to use the two.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like:

```
public void makecall(clsPhone Tphone, clsPhone Rphone)
{
    Tphone.ringPhone();
    Rphone.ringPhone();
}
```

So then you'd do

```
public static void main()
{
    var phone1 = incoming(213123) // just sample values, idk what int TransmitPhoneLoc is
    var phone2 = Outgoing(345435)
    makecall(phone1, phone2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it even further:

```
public MakeCall(int phoneLocation)
{
    clsPhone phone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[phoneLocation];
    phone.ringPhone();
}

...

MakeCall(transmitPhoneLoc);
MakeCall(receivePhoneLoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after.....

```
public clsPhone Tphone(int TransmitPhoneLoc)
{
clsPhone tempPhone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[TransmitPhoneLoc];
return tempPhone
}

public clsPhone Rphone(int ReceivePhoneLoc)
{
clsPhone tempPhone = (clsPhone)phoneArray[ReceivePhoneLoc];
return tempPhone
}

public void makecall()
{
//use
Tphone(1234).ringPhone();
//or
Rphone(1234).ringPhone();
}
```

Comment: Not 100% but put on the answer!! Thanx.

Comment: Not sure you want to have two methods that do the same thing there

Comment: @DylanJackson: Please don't use 2 methods that do the same thing

Comment: @Dilvid - read up on the DRY principle...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: @James I know the principles, done them day in day out for last 10+ years. I just adjust the users code to work so he would understand the answer. No point over-complicating something, best to speak at the level the OP post at.

Comment: Well if you know the principles then why don't you apply them? Using a single function to perform the se task instead of 2 isn't over complicating, it's *simplifying*. If anything, duplicating code is more complicating as your having to make changes to different areas instead of one.

Comment: @James As I said ' best to speak at the level the OP post at.'